# in search for explanation of short snippet of python code, bubble sort

Tags: python, bubble-sort

As I am going through the book Python Workshop, on the topic of Bubble sort algorithms, I came upon this snippet of code:

```
l = [5, 8, 1, 3, 2]
still_swapping = True
while still_swapping:
    still_swapping = False
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
            still_swapping = True
```

As I understand the premise of the code, comparing the values one by one and replacing them in correct order, I do not understand what is happening here:

`l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]`

Of course, I can write such code myself, here is my beginner version:

```
l = [5, 8, 1, 3, 2]
still_swapping = True
while still_swapping:
    still_swapping = False
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            temp = l[i]
            l[i] = l[i+1]
            l[i+1] = temp
            still_swapping = True

print(l)
```

But the question is, what is that shortened version of the code that is provided in the book? What kind of operation is taking place? I don't understand the syntax here. Can't really find it in the previous chapters of the book.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between your code and the shortened code is this line:

```
l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
```

What this does is it assigns 2 objects at a time. For example,

```
a, b = c, d
```

assigns `a = c` and `b = d` at the same time.

This isn't limited to just variable assignments, it also works for for-loops:

```
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
```

This will iterate through the indexes and the item at the same time.

One last thing to note is that you can assign more than 2 at a time.

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

will work as expected.

So this shortened code simply assigns `l[i] = l[i+1]` and `l[i+1] = l[i]` at the same time, thus eliminating the need for an extra line defining a temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

`l[i+1], l[i]` creates an anonymous two element tuple of the two indexed values on the right hand side. Tuple unpacking lets you expand a tuple into variables on the left hand side. Just like `foo, bar = 1, 2`, the values in that created tuple are expanded into the left hand side `l[i], l[i+1]`. The effect is that the two values of the list are swapped.

You can see the swap in action by assigning that temporary tuple.

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> i = 0
>>> tmp = l[i+1], l[i]
>>> print(tmp)
(2, 1)
>>> l[i], l[i+1] = tmp
>>> print(l)
[2, 1]
```